# Django-Rest-Framework: documenting parameters of function-based view without model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So, I have a function-based view on a DRF application that looks something like this:

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework import status

def passcode_generator(callsign: str) -> int:
    return 0 # Placeholder


@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def get_passcode(request):
    callsign = request.data.get("callsign", None)
    if callsign is None:
        raise Response(
            {"error": "Missing callsign"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )
    return Response({"passcode": passcode_generator(callsign)})
```

Clearly, `"callsign"` is the only expected argument, and it is mandatory. And that `"passcode"` is the only field in the response. But DRF doesn't know that.

This means that DRF's web-browsable API page can't show the HTML form tab, and means that documentation generators can't properly document it:

[image: Swagger-UI showing the API docs without arguments or return value]

So the question is, **how can one document this function-based view?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this could be done with vanilla DRF. The best schema generator for Django being supported now, as far as I know, is [`drf-spectacular`](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular). So if you are using `drf-spectacular`, you have to document it this way:

```py
@extend_schema(
    parameters=[
        OpenApiParameter(name='callsign', description='<description>', 
                         required=True, type=str),
    ],
    description='More descriptive text'
)
def get_passcode(request):
    callsign = request.data.get("callsign", None)
    # ...
```

Response could be documented this way, according to [tests](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/blob/1f7cf5d8342f5ed3f619afcf92fb43e3b4ff26cb/tests/test_regressions.py#L1744):

```py
    @extend_schema_view(
        create=extend_schema(description='creation description', responses={
            201: OpenApiResponse(response=int, description='creation with int response.'),
            222: OpenApiResponse(description='creation with no response.'),
            223: None,
            224: int,
        }),
        list=extend_schema(responses=OpenApiResponse(
            response=OpenApiTypes.INT,
            description='a list that actually returns numbers',
            examples=[OpenApiExample('One', 1), OpenApiExample('Two', 2)],
        )),
    )
```

Comment: I am indeed already using `drf-spectacular` indeed. Thanks, that is a helpful start. But the documentation on `OpenApiResponse` is very slim though. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Ah, I thought that you have an issue only with the request part. Yeah, docs are definitely not in their best condition. You can refer [tests](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/blob/1f7cf5d8342f5ed3f619afcf92fb43e3b4ff26cb/tests/test_regressions.py#L1744) to have your examples.

Comment: A simple example of a function-based view with `drf-spectacular`: https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/issues/635#issuecomment-1016512020

Comment: `OpenApiResponse` is a special structure to inject extra information that cannot be given otherwise. This is only very rarely needed, e.g. status-code dependent description text. Examples can also be provided without it, but it's slightly more convenient in complicated annotations.